# Calling external function from inline JS

Tags: javascript, function, inline, external

**EDIT:**

I have fixed the cache and tried with fresh installation and now both buttons seem to be working.

## Original Question

I am trying to get an inline JS block to run a function that is externally defined and included to the HTML file. Below are the codes;

```js
function externaltest() {
  alert("i am working!");
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function demo() {
      externaltest();
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="demo()">CLICK ME PLEASE</button>
  <button onclick="externaltest()">I'M WORKING ALREADY</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Now while the first button on the HTML file returns an error about "externaltest function is not defined", the second button works perfectly fine. How can I make the initial button work and call the function that is declared externally?

Comment: Maybe you should try moving your scripts imports at the end of the body just before ```</body>```

Comment: as I have explained in the question, the second button works perfectly fine and alerts the text declared on external function. so i think it's not an issue with src path. and also changing it to `"./functions.js"` doesn't fix the issue too.

Comment: Both of these work. I can't your normal setup, hence I'm not sure what would be wrong. I can think of few different reasons why it won't work but whether it's any of them or none, I can't say. Please include a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Both buttons should be working (they are working for me).
If the first button is not working, reason is likely that the external file `functions.js` could not be loaded.
Check your browser console for errors.